# React: Error - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been having some trouble with this code and cant seem to fix it. I'd appreciate any help.

The error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
Check the render method of `App`.
```

This is my index.js code:

```js
   import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';



ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

And my App.js:

```js
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import AllMeetupsPage from './pages/AllMeetups';
import NewMeetupPage from './pages/NewMeetup';
import FavoritesPage from './pages/Favorites';


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route path='/' exact>
      <AllMeetupsPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/new-meetup'>
      <NewMeetupPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/favoriters'>
      <FavoritesPage />
      </Route>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: You need to show how you export all your pages, as the error states

Comment: its a function and => export default PageName;

Comment: Edit your actual question, seems like its not a function